# How to implement an exception in a .htaccess redirect rule

Tags: .htaccess

I need the URL `www.example.com/foo/bar/*` to be redirected to `www.example.com/sites/default/files/myapp/index.html` in all cases except for `www.example.com/foo/bar/api`.

This is the redirect rule I have now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo/bar(/?.*)$ /sites/default/files/myapp/$1 [L]
```

When the last part is 'api' though the rule should not redirect to index.html, in fact it should not be handled at all. How can I build a rule that accomplishes this?

I have tried this, but it results in a white screen:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/foo/bar/api$
  RewriteRule ^foo/bar(/?.*)$ /sites/default/files/myapp/index.html [L]
```

Some background... the myapp folder is a symbolic folder that points to a folder outside the web root, where I have a separate app working.

Comment: You cannot rewrite to a folder outside your `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: anubhava: Well, actually this is working. Thanks to the symlink I am redirecting to a folder inside the root and the app is executing just fine. It's just the last part to exclude a certain path that I am struggling with.

Comment: `it results in a white screen`: Can you check Apache access.log and error.log to see what is actual error?